# Slow SimpleXML retrieval of records from multiple XML files

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml, pubmed

I am using the Entrez E-Utilities ESearch function to determine the number of results for a set of search terms.

There are 15 searches in the set. The below function takes about 30 seconds to run:

```
<?php
$searches = $this->db->query("SELECT id, term FROM searches")->result();
foreach($searches as $s){        
    $xml =  simplexml_load_file('https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term='.$s->term.'&rettype=count&retmode=xml');
    echo 'Search: '.$s->id.', Count: '.$xml->Count.'<br>';
}
```

Loading the XML file manually in the browser is near instant. I'm not sure why it is taking so long to loop through the 15 searches and retrieve the Count attribute. Any help would be much appreciated!

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/#_chapter4_ESearch_

Comment: The first rule of debugging: break down your problem, isolate the issue. There are two very steps obvious here: loading the list from the database; and downloading and parsing the XML. So, run just the SQL; how long does that take? Now remove the SQL and hard-code a single URL; how long does that take? Then dig a little deeper: if it's in the SQL, you can dig further into the code. If it's the XML, you can separate the downloading (e.g. use `file_get_contents`) and the parsing (e.g. use `simplexml_load_string`). Carry on until you have a clearly isolated problem.